# [Java - File]Not able to read the entire .txt using FileInputStream/ObjectInputStream in an ArrayList object account_Info

Tags: java, arraylist, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

I am working on a small project in JAVA to write and read to a file using `FileOutputStream/FileInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream` and when I tried to read the entire `.txt` file, the code only read the first line of the `.txt` file.

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class account_Read implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    account_Info data = new account_Info();
    ArrayList<account_Info> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    public void read() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("bankAccount.txt");
            ObjectInputStream objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

            accounts = (ArrayList<account_Info>) objectIn.readObject();

            System.err.println("Open file");
            objectIn.close();
            fileIn.close();
        } catch (Exception et) {
            et.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void displayAccount(int accountID) {
        read(); // read the file to load the accounts into the ArrayList

        boolean accountFound = false;

        for (account_Info account : accounts) {
            if (account.getaccountID() == accountID) {
                int id = account.getaccountID();
                String name = account.getFirstname();
                String last = account.getSurname();
                double balance = account.getBalance();
                double overdraft = account.getOverdraft();

                System.out.println("Account Number: " + id);
                System.out.println("Account Balance: " + balance);
                System.out.println("Account Overdraft: " + overdraft);
                System.out.println("Account Holder Name: " + name + " " + last);
                System.out.println("---------------------------");

                accountFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!accountFound) {
            System.out.println("Account not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to loop this block code using the while/for loop and even changing the ArrayList to object account_Info accounts, however, I was not able to read all the files.

```
accounts = (ArrayList<account_Info>) objectIn.readObject();
```

Comment: *however I was not able to read all the file.* Meaning? How many objects are in your `List`?